# Programmaticaly Get SNMP request and response in hex format using SNMP4j

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I am a newbie to SNMP4J world and trying my hands with SNMP4j for managing a device.Please find the code inline. I need the request and response data payload in hex format.I am able to get the request and response but as java object . Please find the ouput

Program :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
    TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
    transport.listen();
    CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
    comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
    comtarget.setVersion(snmpVersion);
    comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
    comtarget.setRetries(2);
    comtarget.setTimeout(1000);
    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oidValue)));
    pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
    pdu.setRequestID(new Integer32(1));
    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

    System.out.println("Sending Request to Agent...");
    PDU requestPDU=snmp.get(pdu, comtarget).getRequest();

    System.out.println("request : "+requestPDU);
    ResponseEvent response = snmp.get(pdu, comtarget);

  if (response != null)
    {
      System.out.println("Got Response from Agent");
      PDU responsePDU = response.getResponse();

      if (responsePDU != null)
      {
        int errorStatus = responsePDU.getErrorStatus();
        int errorIndex = responsePDU.getErrorIndex();
        String errorStatusText = responsePDU.getErrorStatusText();

        if (errorStatus == PDU.noError)
        {
          System.out.println("Snmp Get Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings());
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Error: Request Failed");
          System.out.println("Error Status = " + errorStatus);
          System.out.println("Error Index = " + errorIndex);
          System.out.println("Error Status Text = " + errorStatusText);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Error: Response PDU is null");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Error: Agent Timeout... ");
    }
    snmp.close();
  }
```

Output :

```
Sending Request to Agent...
request : GET[requestID=1, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = Null]]
Got Response from Agent
Snmp Get Response = [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = Dell Networking N3048, 6.0.1.3, Linux 3.6.5-320b2282]
```

Comment: Your program is printing the variable bindings already. I gather that you need the printout to look different. But why would you want them as hex format? The data you're requesting is clearly not "binary" data, but text strings. So, it would seem correct that they are printed as they are, when you are (implicitly) calling the toString() method with `"Snmp Get Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings()`.

Comment: Here's an idea, if you want to see the hex data of the PDU, sniff the traffic using Wireshark!

Comment: I am able to sniff the traffic using wireshark and get the response in hex format.But I need to programmatically get the request in Hex format (also byte format will do which can be converted into hex). The reason is that I have a C client sitting at my device end which acts as a router to send the request instead of Using the SNMP4j client to send the request to device.So I need a inform request constructed using the SNMP4J library.

Comment: Well, in that case, just convert the String values, as supplied by toString(), into `byte[]` or similar.